# Ask the definition of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, statistics

For example I am focusing on $E(A|B)$. Both A and B are random variables. Now I need to keep conditioning on C. How should I write? $E(A|B)=E(E(A|B) | C )$ or $E(A|B)=E(E(A|B,C))$?

Comment: None of the above are correct; the latter is obviously wrong since it's the lhs is stochastic and the rhs is constant.

Comment: @Andrew but the first one should be correct. Consider $Y=A|B$, then it is reduced to $E(Y)=E(E(Y|C))$. This is the law of total expectation.

Comment: Just because it does not contradict total expectation means nothing. It's akin to saying $E(Y\mid X) = E(Y\mid Z)$. In any case, the first one is obviously wrong as well since the left hand side is $B$ measurable whereas the right hand side is $C$ measurable

Comment: There is no such thing as $Y=A|B$. You may want either $E[E[A|B]|C]$ or $E[A|(B,C)]$, these are different things. The first is a function of $C$, the second is a function of $(B,C)$.  It is not clear what you want when you say "Now I need to keep conditioning on $C$."

Comment: If you want a conditioned version of the law of iterated expectations for random variables $X,Y,Z$, it is $$E[X|Y] = E[E[X|Y,Z]|Y]$$